# How to fetch data before navigating in AngularDart?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I want to fetch all data from remote service at once before routing to Profile.

I find typescript version angular have **Resolve** to help to fetch data before navigating. But I cannot find any example in Dart version ( angular2: ^3.0.0).

```
@RouteConfig(const [
  const Route(path: '/', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent, useAsDefault: true]),
  const Route(path: '/profile', name: 'Profile', component: ProfileComponent),])
class AppComponent implements OnInit{

}
```

Anyone know how to handle it by using Dart?

Comment: The current router in Angular.dart doesn't have `Resolve`. Depending on what exactly you try to accomplish, there might be different workarounds. It was also mentioned that a new router for Angular.dart is work in progress (might still take a while though)

Comment: Tks for your reply. I want to get all required data before rendering a ProfileComponent because I try to prevent saturation when browser rendered all static content and some child component in ProfileComponent still waiting for async Http result. 

I want my UI display as a whole like a server side rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current router in Angular.dart doesn't have `Resolve`.
Depending on what exactly you try to accomplish, there might be different workarounds.

Usually just wrapping the content of the components template with

```
<template [ngIf]="data != null"> ... </template>
```

should do, and then assign to `data` when it's available and the component will be shown.

Another more generic way might be to create a custom `MyRouterOutlet` that might extend `RouterOutlet` and customize it so that it delays adding the component until an event was received.

Add to the `RouterOutlet`

```
@HostBinding() 
dataArrived() {
  // call the code that actually adds the component
}
```

then use it like

```
<router-outlet fetchDataDirective></router-outlet>
```

and a directive like

```
@Directive(selector: '[fetchDataDirective]')
class FetchDataDirective implements OnInit {
  final DataService dataService;
  FetchDataDirective(this.dataService);

  @Output() 
  get dataArrived => _dataArrived.stream; 
  final _dataArrived = new StreamController(); 

  ngOnInit() async {
    await dataService.fetchData();
  }
}
```

that emits the event the `RouterOutlet` waits for.

It was also mentioned that a new router for Angular.dart is work in progress (might still take a while though).